# $f(x)=(x+1)e^{x^2}$ Taylor expansion with Lagrange error

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

$$f(x)=(x+1)e^{x^2}$$

Find the Taylor expansion up to order $4$ around $x_0=1$, and find an approximation of $f(\frac 1 2)$ with error less than $10^{-3}$.

I can take several derivatives and do it by hand, but I wonder if there is a way to use the well known expansion of $e^x$, which is valid everywhere but is centered in $0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Calculate the derivatives and save time for everybody.

Comment: Hint: 
Let $x^2=X$, then when $x$ is around $1$, $X$ is also around $1$. So write the Taylor expansion of $e^X$ around $1$ and then substitute $X$ by the Taylor expansion of $x^2$ around $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is: first you have to rewrite all as a polynomial in $x-1$:
\begin{align}f(x)&=(x+1)e^{x^2}\\&=((x-1)+2)e^{(x-1)^2}e^{2(x-1)}\cdot e^1\\
&=((x-1)+2)\sum\frac{(x-1)^{2n}}{n!}\cdot\sum\frac{2(x-1)^m}{m!}\cdot e\\ &=\sum a_n(x-1)^n\end{align}
And now find the $a_n$... but honestly this might take more time than calculating the derivatives...

The other way (as Hamza pointed out) is to write
\begin{align}f(x)&=(x+1)e^{x^2}=(x+1)\cdot\sum_n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}\\
&=((x-1)+2)\cdot\sum_n\frac{((x-1)+1)^{2n}}{n!}\\
&=((x-1)+2)\cdot\sum_n\frac{\sum_k {2n\choose k}(x-1)^k}{n!}\end{align}
Then change the order of summation to get again something of the form $\sum a_n(x-1)^n$